# PHP Forms/SQL Error: Unexpected End of File

Tags: php, sql

All I'm trying to do is perform an SQL query to transfer data from each text input box in the form to a database.  I keep receiving the following error for DatabaseStuff.php:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   /home/ar04063/public_html/DatabaseStuff.php on line 38

What am I doing wrong?  Is there anything else that I need to do to be getting it working properly?  Here's some sample code:

XYZSurvey.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'Form.php';
require_once 'RadioButton.php';
require_once 'TextInput.php';
require_once 'Validator.php';

$form = new Form();

$form -> addInput(new TextInput("First Name: ", "first_name"));
$form -> addInput(new TextInput("Last Name: ", "last_name"));
$form -> addInput(new TextInput("Age: ", "ice_cream_flavor"));
$radio1 = new RadioButton("Gender:", "gender");
$radio1 -> addOption("Male", "male");
$radio1 -> addOption("Female", "female");
$form -> addInput($radio1);
$form -> addInput(new TextInput("Email: ", "email_address"));

$form -> addInput(new TextInput("", "","Submit","","",false,"submit"));

echo $form -> generateHTML();
```

DatabaseStuff.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'XYZSurvey.php';

$host = "localhost";
$username = "W********";
$password = "**********";
$dbname = "W01104063";
$firstname = $_POST["first_name"];
$lastname = $_POST["last_name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$gender = $_POST["gender"];

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Sorry, an error occured.";
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

$stmtSurvey = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO PersonalInfo (firstname, lastname, email, gender) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$gender');
$stmtSurvey->bindValue(':firstname', 'Ashley');
$stmtSurvey->bindValue(':lastname', 'Richardson');
$stmtSurvey->bindValue(':email', 'null');
$stmtSurvey->bindValue(':gender', 'null');

$stmtSurvey->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //Set Fetch mode to Assoc
$stmtSurvey->execute();

while($survey = $stmtSurvey->fetch())
{
    var_dump($survey);
}
```

Comment: Auto highlight suggests you the error!

Comment: Check your query.

Answer (score 3):

Missing closing quotes and closing parenthesis in DatabaseSuff.php at the end of this line :

```
$stmtSurvey = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO PersonalInfo (firstname, lastname, email, gender) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$gender');
```

Replace it with :

```
$stmtSurvey = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO PersonalInfo (firstname, lastname, email, gender) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$gender')");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You missed one closing parentheses:

```
require_once 'XYZSurvey.php';

$host = "localhost";
$username = "W********";
$password = "**********";
$dbname = "W01104063";
$firstname = $_POST["first_name"];
$lastname = $_POST["last_name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$gender = $_POST["gender"];

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Sorry, an error occured.";
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

//You missed 1 closing parentheses here 
$stmtSurvey = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO PersonalInfo(firstname, lastname, email, gender) VALUES ("$firstname", "$lastname", "$email", "$gender")');


$stmtSurvey->bindValue(':firstname', 'Ashley');
$stmtSurvey->bindValue(':lastname', 'Richardson');
$stmtSurvey->bindValue(':email', 'null');
$stmtSurvey->bindValue(':gender', 'null');

$stmtSurvey->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //Set Fetch mode to Assoc
$stmtSurvey->execute();

while($survey = $stmtSurvey->fetch())
{
    var_dump($survey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing one closing parentheses here:

```
$stmtSurvey = $dbh->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO PersonalInfo (firstname, lastname, email, gender)
         VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$gender') ");
                                                                 ^ - this one
```

Comment: You missed closing brackets of the prepare() statement

Comment: Thanks. While copy/paste..